# array anidado problema en php

Tags: php

```
  <?php
  session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
$_SESSION['contador']++;
} 
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['can'] = $_GET['c'];
}

print_r($_SESSION['producto']);
```

resultado 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [can] => 1 [id] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [can] => 1 [id] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [can] => 1 ) )

no se porque solo en la posición 0 se anidan los 2 después se separan y como recorrerían este array en un bucle

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que actualizas el **contador** antes de ingresar la cantidad `can`, entonces siguiendo la lógica que tienes:

1. Sería verificar si existe `$_GET['p']` y no es `NULL`, entonces
   `$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['id'] = $_GET['p'];`.
2. Después se comprueba si existe `$_GET['c']` y no es `NULL`, entonces
   `$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['can'] = $_GET['c'];`
3. Ahora si incrementas el contador `$_SESSION['contador']++;`.

---

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
    if(isset($_GET['c'])){
        $_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']]['can'] = $_GET['c'];
    }
    $_SESSION['contador']++;
}
print_r($_SESSION['producto']);
```

---

Una forma de recorrer sería:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['producto'] as $pro) { 
    print_r($pro);
    //así imprimiría por ejemplo (teniendo un solo producto con id = 1 y can = 3):  
    //Array ( [id] => 1 [can] => 3 )
}
```